# Underscore findWhere usage

Tags: underscore.js

For some reason my findWhere does not work. Is this the correct way to use? I followed the example code from the documentation and it seemed to have similar pattern.

```
var test = _.findWhere(object.entryDetails, {entryOwner_id: customer._id});
```

object.entryDetails has following value,

```
   [{ money_out: 0,
        money_in: 0,
        entryOwner_id: 5738b77b648115cf0410ba92,
        _id: 57393d834d7ab0fa1af85600 },
      { money_out: 0,
        money_in: 0,
        entryOwner_id: 5738b77c648115cf0410baaa,
        _id: 57393d834d7ab0fa1af855ff } ]
```

customer._id has following value

```
5738b77b648115cf0410ba92
```

Clearly the customer._id exists in the array but my findWhere return "undefined"

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that underscore does not use "equals" in comparing the query. Hence the work around would be

```
var filtered = _.filter(object.entryDetails, function (entry) {
     return entry.entryOwner_id.equals(customer._id);});
if (filtered.length > 0) ...
```

Comment: Filter will return an array with all items that pass your validation function, if you're looking for a single item you could use [find](http://underscorejs.org/#find) instead